# ASP.NET Web API: JSON Serializing Circular References

Tags: asp.net, json.net, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2, json-serialization

I am retrieving a JSON object graph via ASP.NET Web API. I'm trying to access the properties from a child entity. When looking at the browser's console, however, it is showing a *reference* (`$ref`) to the object, instead of serializing the properties of that object. How do I get access to these properties?

**ANGULAR JS VIEW**

```html
<table infinite-scroll='tF.loadMore()' infinite-scroll-disabled='tF.isBusy' infinite-scroll-distance='3' class="responsive">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>FIELD 1</th>
            <th>FIELD 2</th>
            <th>FIELD 3</th>
            <th>FIELD 4</th>
            <th>FIELD 5</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in tF.items | filter:searchFilter">
            <td>{{item.CompanyDomainModel.CompanyName}}</td>
            <td>{{item.RatingDomainModel.RatingValue}}</td>
            <td>{{item.Views}}</td>
            <td>{{item.Clicks}}</td>
            <td>{{item.EmailSent}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot ng-show='tF.isBusy'>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="9"><spinner show="tF.isBusy" /><span class="bold">{{tF.status}}</span> </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

**SERVICE**

```cs
public ICollection<CompanyStatDomainModel> GetRecordsByPageSize(int page) { 
  const int pgeSize = 20; 
  var result = _companyStatRepo
    .AllIncluding(c => c.CompanyDomainModel, c => c.RatingDomainModel) 
    .OrderBy(c => c.CompanyStatId)
    .Skip(page * pgeSize)
    .Take(pgeSize)
    .ToList(); 
  return result; 
}
```

**ENDPOINT**

```cs
IHttpActionResult GetRecordsByPageSize(int page) { 
  var companyStatService = new CompanyStatService(); 
  return Ok(companyStatService.GetRecordsByPageSize(page)); 
}
```

**RATING DOMAIN MODEL**

```cs
public class RatingDomainModel : IObjectWithState
{
  [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
  [DataMember]
  public int RatingId { get; set; }

  [DataMember]
  public int CompanyId { get; set; }

  [DataMember]
  public int UserId { get; set; }

  [DataMember]
  public int RatingValue { get; set; }

  [DataMember]
  public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

  //[ForeignKey("UserId")]
  [DataMember]
  public virtual UserDomainModel UserDomainModel { get; set; }

  //[ForeignKey("CompanyId")]
  [DataMember]
  public virtual CompanyDomainModel CompanyDomainModel { get; set; }

  [DataMember]
  public virtual ICollection<CompanyStatDomainModel> CompanyStatDomainModels { get; set; }

  [NotMapped]
  public Common.DataObject.State state { get; set; }

  [NotMapped]
  public bool InDb
  {
    get { return this.RatingId != default(int); }
  }

  public object PersistenceEntityId
  {
    get { return this.RatingId; }
  }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image: Please see below URL to see the results I am getting from the API]

Comment: Note: I don't think the AngularJS code or tag add much value here. This is really a question regarding ASP.NET Web API, and will be true independent of what your client code is written in.

Comment: As an aside, do you have a lot invested into your API and client already? If not, you may want to consider making an OData controller instead. OData addresses this issue elegantly by allowing projection to be defined using a consistent Query String parameter. E.g., in this case you'd be able to use `?$expand=RatingDomainModel`. This is a pretty big architectural shift, but if you're early in the project it may provide additional benefits.

Comment: Also, could you post the code from your controller for this particular endpoint? Knowing how you're currently exposing these objects will be useful.

Comment: I have invested a lot into the API.                                                                                The below code is my service                                                                                    public ICollection<CompanyStatDomainModel> GetRecordsByPageSize(int page)
        {
            const int pgeSize = 20;

            var result = _companyStatRepo.AllIncluding(c => c.CompanyDomainModel, c => c.RatingDomainModel)
                .OrderBy(c => c.CompanyStatId).Skip(page * pgeSize).Take(pgeSize).ToList();

            return result;
        }

Comment: Controller                                                                                                                   public IHttpActionResult GetRecordsByPageSize(int page)
       {
           var companyStatService = new CompanyStatService();

           return Ok(companyStatService.GetRecordsByPageSize(page));
       }

Comment: OK. I've added this code to your question so it's easy for other reviewers to reference. I've also deleted my originally proposed answer because, upon seeing your code, it's clear that you're already using the `Include()` method (or, rather, the related `AllIncluding()` method).

Comment: It's strange, because i can get the company entity field "Company Name" populated but i can not get the Rating Entity field "RatingValue"

Comment: @JeremyCaney: In future, it's probably best to mention that you got the extra code *from comments*, as otherwise it looks to reviewers like you just made it up.

Comment: @ErkanDemir: Ah, I hadn't paid close enough attention to the output originally; I see what you're talking about now. Can you edit your post to include the `RatingDomainModel` class? Also, what is the data type for the `RatingValue` property?

Comment: @JeremyCaney, just posted it up

Comment: @JeremyCaney i got it working. I add the below code into my WebApiConfig.cs   config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.None;

Comment: @ErkanDemir Aha! Congratulations. For the sake of future viewers, would you mind adding that as an answer? (You can answer your own question).

Comment: @ErkanDemir consider use another layer between the model of the API and the model of how you store the data.

Answer (score 22):

Added the below code into WebApiConfig.cs

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling =    Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.None;
```

Comment: This helped me out big time! I was almost about to give up and start tearing apart my whole data model. Thanks